# where to put properties file in project (no resources folder is there)

Tags: eclipse, properties-file

Where do i keep my properties file in eclipse .As per my knowledge we keep it in resources folder but there is no resources folder by default.
This is the project structure-
[image]

can anyone plz help me with this

Comment: Create a resources folder under Java Resources.  Add the resources folder to the class path.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the Java Resources folder, make the resources folder.  And then once you have made that add the folder to the class path.